# Purpose Built-in Control, but with error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Tags: excel, vba, callback, ribbon-control, ribbonx

I was trying to repurpose a built-in control. Using similar RibbonX code and VBA code, I found that some controls can be repurposed (for examples, Paste and FileSave), and some cannot be repurposed (for examples, Bold and Underline).
The error message was "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment".

RibbonX code:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <commands>
        <command idMso="Underline" enabled="false"/>
        <command idMso="Bold" onAction="MyBold"/>
    </commands>
</customUI>
```

In a standard VBA module:

```
'Callback for Bold onAction
Sub MyBold(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef cancelDefault)
    MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
```

In Excel when I clicked on the Bold control, I got the error message:

> Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Searching the internet for examples [this site](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/09fc3ede-5db8-42c0-9d21-d46c2e2c2272/error-message-when-repurposing-ribbon-controls?forum=worddev) 
and [another site](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/be0734ac-68f6-4f47-a922-5343a5f7b0c9/issue-when-disabling-context-menu-and-shortcuts-in-word-documents?forum=worddev), do not provide me any clue.

Really appreciate your thoughts. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong callback signature. See this document:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

The Bold button is in fact a togglebutton control, so you should be using:

```
Sub MyBold(control As IRibbonControl, pressed As Boolean, ByRef cancelDefault)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, jkpieterse. Now it works. My UI editor generated me a callback with wrong number of arguments.

Comment: I had the same issue when I was trouble-shooting yours :-)